# Changing Target Environment at Boot Time interactively

Tags: linux, boot, systemd

Is there a way to change the target when Linux starts? What I would like is to change the target interactively at boot time so that I can decide if, for example, start Linux in multi-user or in graphical mode.
So far I have only found information on Fedora (which I assume is also valid on other distributions) that plans to add the string systemd.unit = multi-user.target to the grub boot options (by editing).
I found some information on the simple-window-dialog.service service but I do not know if it's the correct way ...

Answer (score 0):

First check your default runlevel or target using

```
#systemctl get-default
```

If you want to set multi-user.target,  use this command

```
# systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

If you want to set graphical, use

```
##systemctl set-default graphical.target
```